# Get error when trying to download a CSV file created from my database

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to download a simple CSV file from my database using the inbuilt PHP function `fputcsv()`.

Here is my function:

```
/**
 * downloads class logs in csv format
 */
public function ajaxDownloadTeachersClassLogs()
{
    // ...code to get data from the database...
    $classes = $query->result();

    // download file
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");

    // write data to file
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        fputcsv($output, $class);
    }
    // change delimiter/enclosure
    fclose($output);
}
```

I know that my database query is correct because when I `var_dump($classes);` I get the following result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (10) {
    ["token"]=>
    string(5) "9DFCF"
    ["teacher_name"]=>
    string(17) "James Dean" 
    ["teacher_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["student_name"]=>
    string(11) "Juan Santos"
    ["student_id"]=>
    string(2) "26"
    ["class_number"]=>
    string(3) "1/1"
    ["started"]=>
    string(10) "1488279490"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(4) "1200"
    ["invite_email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["status"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

When I run the function I get the following error:

[image]

If I click okay the download fails.

Why is my download failing?

**EDIT:**

It looks like my issues were to do with a content encoding error I had that was cased by a misconfiguration in the framework I was using...

The code below works:

```
$this->db->order_by('started');
$query = $this->db->get('classes');

header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv;');

$flag = false;
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    if ($flag === false) {
        fputcsv($output, array_keys($row), ',');
    }
    fputcsv($output, array_values($row), ',');
}
die;
```

Comment: you can use like this.

$fp = fopen ('file.csv','w');

fputcsv($fp, $data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps:

- First of all make a CSV with some **hard-code** data, to check if the same issue  occurs.
- If issue stills occur with hard-code data then:

  `$output = fopen("php://output", "w");`

instead of this write the file in some project `directory` and see what happens.

Comment: Right, still get an error with hardcoded data... problem is probably your second suggestion

Comment: Try the second option and then let me know what happens

Comment: Hi Mayank, I was wrong, the first option actually works, I am sure that the problem is that I am getting my db result ad an associative array but it needs to be a numeric array! Thanks for your help!

Comment: So change your array accordingly and try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136855/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-jethro-hazelhurst).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in fputcsv() for your arrays to generate correct csv lines from your array, so you will have to loop over and collect the lines. like:

```
   // open raw memory as file so no temp files needed, you might run out of memory though
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
    // loop over the input array
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        fputcsv($output, $class);
    }
    // reset the file pointer to the start of the file
    fseek($f, 0);
    // tell the browser it's going to be a csv file
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    // tell the browser we want to save it instead of displaying it
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    // make php send the generated csv lines to the browser
    fpassthru($f);
```